# MySQL insert NULL instead of 0000-00-00 date

Tags: php, mysql, date, null

I have birthday column as a date defined in my table. When i insert a person and left blank birthday field, i get 0000-00-00 and i want to get NULL values. when i insert date as birthday i get date, which is fine.

i tried :

```
Create table (
birthday DATE NULL,
birthday DATE DEFAULT NULL,
birthday DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
);
```

doesn't work, please a little advice to get NULL instead of 0000-00-00 in my birthday fields.
my php script:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO users (birthday, other_column, data_registration) VALUES ('$birthday', '$other_column', NOW())
```

i get no solution yet, any ideea please?

Comment: You define a 3 column with same name in one table?

Comment: If you want the value to be `NULL` then pass `NULL` in your SQL query (and not quoted in a string)

Comment: i must used a quote in a string

Comment: i have 105 columns in my table, here i write an example.

Comment: You have 105 columns in your table? We need to talk about your table.

Comment: not all the time i need to be NULL, just when i miss/left birthday blank

Comment: what about my table? has 106 columns, 4200 records and about 12 fields as date type which has the same problem. in my fields(as date) i get 0000-00-00 when i not introduce any date and i need to get blank (NULL)

Answer (score 3):

What is in your `$birthday`?

Suppose you have `$birthday = null` or `$birthday = "null"`, you will get `0000-00-00`. This is because when it's passing to your query, it becomes something like (I believe it's treating your `'null'` or `null` as a string, because you have single quotes around it):

```
INSERT INTO users (birthday, other_column, data_registration) VALUES ('null', '$other_column', NOW())
```

Instead try this, which the 2 single quotes around `$birthday` are removed:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO users (birthday, other_column, data_registration) VALUES ($birthday, '$other_column', NOW())
```

Here is an alternative fix:

```
if ($birthday) {
$q = "INSERT INTO b (birthday, other_column, data_registration) VALUES ('$birthday', '$other_column', NOW())";
} else {
$q = "INSERT INTO b (birthday, other_column, data_registration) VALUES (DEFAULT, '$other_column', NOW())";
}
```

Comment: $dayn=$_POST['dayn'];
                $monthn=$_POST['monthn'];
                $yearn=$_POST['yearn'];
                $birthday = $yearn.'-'.$monthn.'-'.$dayn;

Answer (score 1):

if you use `birthday DATE DEFAULT NULL,` in your create statemnt and use

```
INSERT INTO users (other_column) VALUES ( '$other_column')
```

You should get `null´in`birthday` column.

Comment: i get 0000-00-00, and i want NULL value, i defined NULL DEFAULT NULL in birthday statement when i create the table

Answer (score 0):

If you want to EXPLICITLY insert null into the table, then you will need to insert  NULL from PHP.

If you want to leave the table to assume its default value, then either OMIT the column from the insert clause entirely, or otherwise use the literal `DEFAULT` which will apply the default.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    Name VARCHAR(20),
    BirthDate DATE DEFAULT NULL -- Redundant, since a NULLABLE column will default NULL
);

INSERT INTO Person(Name) VALUES('Joe'); -- Default, NULL
INSERT INTO Person(Name, BirthDate) VALUES('Joe', NULL); -- Explicit Null
INSERT INTO Person(Name, BirthDate) VALUES('Joe', DEFAULT); -- Default, NULL
```

[SqlFiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/139d4/1)

If the date in PHP you are inserting is `0000-00-00`, then you will need to apply logic in your code to either substitute `NULL`, `DEFAULT` for the column, or omit the column (or I guess use a trigger, but this is a hack)

Comment: whats happend when i must insert a birthday value? it work's?